# Using MediaPlayer and AVFoundation Framework simultaniously in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, controls, record, ipod

I'm an inexperienced XCode use and programmer in general so keep that in mind.  I'm trying to use the microphone on the iPhone  while at the same time allowing the user to play audio while using the "iPod music picker",  but when the user selects music and plays it the recorder stops working? I have no idea what is going on here? Also, on a side note, how do you implement forward and back iPod buttons?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this is an Audio Session issue - you're probably in a mode where you can either play or record, but not both at the same time.

Check out the [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW4) which should explain how to configure your session.

> AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord — Use this category for an application that inputs and outputs audio. The input and output need not occur simultaneously, but can if needed. This is the category to use for audio chat applications.
>
> AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient - This category allows audio from the iPod, Safari, and other built-in applications to play while your application is playing audio. You could, for example, use this category for an application that provides a virtual musical instrument that a user plays along to iPod audio.